# 535, b'Error: authentication failed when using os.environ to get the password

Tags: django, environment-variables, smtp

I'm trying to setup the password-reset route on Django, for not showing the account and the password directly in the code, I set them in the Mac environment, but keep getting the 535 error. its working if I write the password in the code, but getting error through "os.environ.get".

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'THESAMEPASSWORD'//this line works
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')//this line getting error
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't those your database's auth details?

Comment: I just set the variable this way, it will export my email and password. or should I not use the DB_PASS as the name? but as I test it in another file, vs code prints out the right data

Comment: "I set them in the Mac environment" Show how you do that.

Comment: I added the pic upon the question description.(but edited the the password and the email

Comment: Can you `print(os.environ.get('DB_PASS'))` to make sure  .zprofile is sourced?

Comment: Yes I did. and it printed out the right data.

Comment: Then `os.environ` is not the problem.